# Memory usage of [][]string vs struct containing []string

Tags: go, memory, struct, memory-leaks, slice

When appending to a `[][]string` profiling shows the app uses around 145MiB of memory.

```
defer profile.Start(profile.MemProfile).Stop()

f, _ := os.Open("test.csv") // 100 MiB File
r := csv.NewReader(f)

var records [][]string
for {
    values, err := r.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    records = append(records, values)
}
```

When storing the slice in a struct and appending that the app uses around 260MiB of memory.

```
defer profile.Start(profile.MemProfile).Stop()

type record struct {
    values []string
}

f, _ := os.Open("test.csv") // 100 MiB File
r := csv.NewReader(f)

var records []record
for {
    values, err := r.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    r := record{values: values}
    records = append(records, r)
}
```

It feels like it's using double the memory in the second example. Can someone explain why the second example uses more memory?

Comment: Size of `record` and `[]string` is the same. How do you measure used memory?

Comment: @icza We are using `pprof` I've added the line into the question

Comment: Can someone explain why the second example uses more memory? No. Because I doubt that the second actually uses much more mem. Probably an artefact of your measurement.

Comment: A couple of assorted things: 1) In questions like this, one should include the exact Go version and the platform info (GOOS/GOARCH); 2) I'd try to isolate this case into a benchmark and run it with `-benchmem`; 3) You could also try to run your isolated case as a standalone program under `GOGC=off` and sample memory usage at its start and before end using `runtime.ReadMemStats` to see the diff; 4) Use `unsafe.SizeOf` to see the actual sizes of the memory used by `[]string` and `record`. Note that the fact they are equal may actually say very little.

Comment: I did try the 2 versions with benchmarks, and they resulted in identical memory usage.

Comment: For reference, this is how I tested it: https://play.golang.org/p/hH7zGgexHKx Please save it in your file system and run it with `go test -bench . -benchmem`, and tell us what you get. I get nearly identical memory usage and allocations (difference is less than 0.01%).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I ran the second example a few times with `pprof` and one of the times it did come back the same as `[][]string` so sounds like an issue with that test. Will suggest the other things recommended. Thanks again

Comment: So it was non-issue?

Comment: Try to call `runtime.GC()` at the end of main with the help of `runtime.KeepAlive(records)`. Difference in memory usage is not too big (used code from playground by @icza).

Comment: Why not defining record as following?  `type record []string` then there is no struct and you still get the type safety of having a object type record.

Comment: Can you please give some more details on your go environment?

Comment: In the first example, it is an array but in the second example, it is a slice. Slice is a dynamic array, it always has more capacity than the values it currently holds. so based on what you measure as memory (different tests might measure memory allocated differently) you will get different memory.

Comment: @SaiRaviTejaK The code in the question does not use arrays.

Comment: unless OP provides meaningful reproducible example with details of OS, go env etc, the post is not solvable. so i vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are using between go 1.12 and go 1.15, `debug.FreeOSMemory()` would not have returned the free memory back to OS, so htop/top will show wrong number or if you rely on RSS to monitor your app, it would be wrong.

This is due to the fact that runtime in Golang (1.12 - 1.15) uses `MADV_FREE` rather than `MADV_DONTNEED`.<= Go (1.11) and Go (1.16 - which was released couple of days back) use `MADV_DONTNEED`.

Go 1.16 reverted back to `MADV_DONTNEED`.

Please find the changelog image and change log URL [here](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#runtime).

Please upgrade to get predicatable analytics on memory usage. If you want to use GoLang(1.12-1.15) and still want to use `MADV_DONTNEED`, Kindly run your binaries using `GODEBUG=madvdontneed=1` ./main.
[image]

Comment: i dont think this answers the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).